# How to check whether (type of) a manifest is a subtype of manifest[Numberic[_]]?

Tags: scala

First of all, I know that manifests are deprecated and it is better to use TypeTag, but for now, it is not an option for me, so please consider my problem:

How to check whether type represented by a manifest is a subtype of the type represented by manifest[Numberic[_]]?

Actually, I have a function that receives a manifest and I want to check whether it is numeric or not.

```
def isNumeric(m: Manifest[T]) : Boolean = m <:< manifest[Numeric[_]]
```

But, it does not work, e.g. for an input of manifest[Double].

Any idea, how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numeric` is a type class and it has nothing with subtyping and `Manifest` (or `TypeTag`).

`Double` is not a `Numeric`. `T : Numeric` in type parameter means there is implicit value of type `Numeric[T]` in scope. You can't check it via reflection.

Maybe you could search for implicit in `macros`, but I'm not sure and I don't think it's what you are looking for.

So the answer is: You just can't.

It isn't possible even in theory: there is no information about implicit values in runtime and there is no instance of `Manifest[T]` in compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally, I used this object containing isNumeric:

object ManifestOps {
  val doubleManifest: Manifest[Double] = manifest[Double]
  val floatManifest: Manifest[Float] = manifest[Float]
  val longManifest: Manifest[Long] = manifest[Long]
  val intManifest: Manifest[Int] = manifest[Int]
  val shortManifest: Manifest[Short] = manifest[Short]
  val byteManifest: Manifest[Byte] = manifest[Byte]

  def isNumeric[T:Manifest](m: Manifest[T]) = m==doubleManifest ||
    m==floatManifest ||
    m==longManifest ||
    m==intManifest ||
    m==shortManifest ||
    m==byteManifest
}

Comment: @MohammadDashti: Note that there could be other types with type class `Numeric`.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for reminding. However, one can add any other Numeric type inside his program to the definition of this isNumeric function.